# How to identify the middle of the first trough in a waveform?

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, mp3

<sup>([Asked on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/629674/how-to-identify-the-middle-of-the-first-near-zero-trough-in-a-graph) before I found this community)</sup>

I have audio files and timestamped fragment transcriptions that I have force-aligned with third party software.

Unfortunately the software places the end of each fragment right before the start of the next fragment, so if you try to play just one fragment from the audio file it will bleed over to the next fragment.

Here's a visualization of the waveform:
[image: WaveForm 1]

The red line is the automatically produced timestamp for the end of one fragment, and the start of another. The left and right sides are 2 seconds of audio on either end of that timestamp.  As you can see it's placed right up against the next time audio starts to output.

The blue and purple lines are two different algorithms I've used to try to identify the middle of the trough. In this case, the blue one worked, but in others it doesn't:

[image: WaveForm 2]
[image: WaveForm 3]
[image: WaveForm 4]

The data is a list of floating point numbers ranging from 0 to 1.  They represent a normalized and bucketed version of decoded 48Hz mp3 audio.  As you can see, in some cases there's a range of near zero values. In others there's varying degrees of "low volume", but always a visually-identifiable trough.

**Can anyone recommend a method or algorithm for working backwards from the red line and finding the middle of the first trough?**

I am a general software developer and unfortunately don't know much of the math that applies to this domain. I'm about 90% sure there's some method that does exactly this and I just need the name of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Compute a moving average or a moving median $p_a[n]$ of the signal power, with a long enough window that it doesn’t get affected by spurious dips in power.
2. Find the point at which $p_a[n]$ dips below a certain threshold that you define, and the point where it goes back above that threshold. That’s your “trough” window.
3. Finding the middle point in that window is trivial.

These things are trial and error based (especially with a hard threshold. You might want to experiment with a dynamic threshold based on previous median/average values too).

Comment: Thanks! This is essentially the route I took. Having to define a specific, non-dynamic threshold wasn't something I was sure I had to do but it seems like it ended up being the right thing.